# Stop re-sizing date cells of FullCalender when more events added

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

I'm using JQuery [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) in my project and I noticed that the date cells will be expanded if more events are coincide with that date.
Like in this picture, see the date cell for `February 4`
[image]

How can I stop this being happening. I want to display only few events that fits into the cell. If there are more events then they should be displayed when we switched to `week` or `day` view.

Is there any way to do It ?

Comment: I haven't used FullCalendar yet, just had a look on the way the plugin works and I feel there's no easy way to change that behaviour with rewriting some parts of the FullCalendar source code. The main problem  is see is the absolute positioning of events, events are not linked to the date cell but instead are positioned based on the top left corner of the calendar. What can be changed is the total height of the calendar (see basic example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/e4Gcn/) but that won't solve your issue. Y

Comment: Just found your exact problem on the Google code community page, created 2010 and still not fixed. The discussion is pretty long (https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=304&q=height&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars), one idea was to minimize the size of the events but that's still just a crutch. I made a fiddle with an additional hover event, perhaps that helps somehow: http://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/e4Gcn/1/

Comment: @SaschaM78 : the hover event is a nice thought but still the problem remains. Let's see Hope there is a way. Because the way now it has is not pretty :)

Answer (score 0):

you can obtain desired result by referring following link

[viewmore functionality to fullcalendar](https://github.com/lyconic/fullcalendar/commit/b6b2357fa2fe04da8b69eaf04504e8ff89323d54)

you need to add 3 js files date.js ,fullcaleder.viewmore.js,jquery.formbubble.js to your project.
problem with this plugins is ViewMore functionality not working,but you can disable viewMoreButton by editing fullcaleder.viewmore.js file and you can get limited number of events in month view and actual events in week view

Answer (score 0):

FullCalendar v2.1.0-beta2 introduces an `eventLimit` option that resolves this.

See https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/releases/tag/v2.1.0-beta2 for rough documentation on the new options introduced by addressing this issue: https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=304 (as SaschaM78 noted before).

I've prepared a JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/wijgerden/nv4qkLgt/ that has example events as shown in the original screenshot. Plus some extra events on 5/6 Feb 2014 to show the effect of `eventLimit: 5`: the 5 events `m1`...`m5` are all visible at once, while the 6 events named `n1`...`n6` are only partially shown. They are all revealed when you click on the "+2 more" link. In this case they are all-day events, but this also works for timed events and combinations of all-day and timed events.